# How to autoscroll to the end of RichEdit?

Tags: delphi, scroll, richedit, autoscroll

I never needed to use the TRichEdit before, always used TMemo.

I'd like RichEdit autoscrolling to the end when I add text like TMemo. See how it looks after you add some data:

[image]

As you can see, the scroll bar remains at the top, but I'd like it stayed at the bottom as I added text.

I've 'googled' for solutions but I couldn't find a good and reliable one.

Comment: I don't see the difference. I tried `Memo1.Lines.Add('test')` and `RichEdit1.Lines.Add('test')` and they behave the same way. You need to specify more details.

Comment: @Andreas, I put more details. I hope to be clearer now.

Comment: @Daniel: Apparently you do not add text by doing `RichEdit1.Lines.Add('text')`. Are you using `SelText := 'text'` instead?

Comment: @Andreas, I'm using `RichEdit1.Lines.Add('text')`

Comment: @Andreas: If we use RichEdit1.Lines.Add() method also,  the output is same as above(In D2006)

Comment: Yes, now I see! I tried `RichEdit1.Lines.Add('text')` in the `OnClick` of the form, and so the Rich Edit (or memo) had the focus all the time. And then both the Rich Edit and the memo scroll. But if the control *has not* focus (e.g., use a `OnClick` of a `TButton`), then only the memo scrolls! Interesting...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this code

```
RichEdit1.SetFocus;
RichEdit1.SelStart := RichEdit1.GetTextLen;
RichEdit1.Perform(EM_SCROLLCARET, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works! I have edit a little your answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: @Daniel: I am not 100 % sure, but I suspect that `RichEdit1.GetTextLength` is **much** faster than `Length(RichEdit1.Text)`. The former only sends a `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` message to the Rich Edit window (as Microsoft wants you to do), whereas the other first have to obtain the entire text as a string (potentially very slow?), and then reads the length cardinal of it (very fast). UPDATE: Sorry, you wanted to use `GetTextLen`, and Bharat used `Length`. I mixed you up!

Comment: Well, it was BugFinder who wanted to use GtTextLen AFAICS, but this is all mixed up now.

Comment: I don't know if it's dependent on Windows or Delphi version, but with Delphi 2007 on Windows XP and 7 all I needed was the .Perform line. It worked even without the TRichEdit being focused.

Comment: Just wanted to add that using

   RichEdit1.Perform(EM_SCROLLCARET, 0, 0);

by itself worked great for me (Delphi XE2)

Comment: Yeah, I had to make some major changes based on this `SetFocus` requirement. What I was doing is a log, in which case everything on the form is disabled during writing the log. So I had to manually disable individual controls at a time, rather than the whole container (because you cannot set focus to disabled controls).

Answer (score 11):

Here is much easier and fast solution:

In OnChange event handler just:

`SendMessage(RichEdit1.handle, WM_VSCROLL, SB_BOTTOM, 0);`

Original answer from: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21002277/Richedit-autoscrolling.html

Answer (score 1):

In short, you need to place the cursor at the end, or send code to scroll down.

Have you tried

```
Richedit1.SelStart :=RichEdit1.GetTextLength();
SendMessage(RichEdit1.handle, EM_SCROLLCARET,0,0);
```

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. You have to put `RichEdit1.SetFocus` before. And at least in Delphi 2010 you have to use `GetTextLen` instead of `GetTextLength`

Comment: Thats kinda irritating, Im surprised it needs focus. (the getTextLength was from memory, so Im not too surprised sorry)